# CUDA Zero Copy vs. CudaMemcpy on Jetson TK1

Tags: c++, mobile, cuda, gpu

My Question:
I am looking for someone to either point out a mistake in the way I am attempting to use implement zero-copy in CUDA, or reveal a more 'behind the scenes' perspective to why the zero-copy method would not be faster than memcpy method. By the way, I am performing my tests on NVidia's TK1 processor, using Ubuntu.

My problem has to do with efficiently using NVIDIA TK1's (physically) unified memory architecture with CUDA. There are 2 methods NVIDIA provides for GPU/CPU memory transfer abstraction.

1. Unified Memory abstraction (using cudaHostAlloc & cudaHostGetDevicePointer)
2. Explicit copy to host, and from device (using cudaMalloc() & cudaMemcpy)

Short description of my test code: I test out the same cuda kernel using both methods 1 and 2. I expected 1 to be faster given that there is no copy to device of the source data or copy from device of the result data. However, results backwards to my assumption (method # 1 is 50% slower). Below is my code for this test:

```
#include <libfreenect/libfreenect.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <memory.h>
///CUDA///
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

 ///OpenCV 2.4
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

///The Test Kernel///
__global__ void cudaCalcXYZ( float *dst, float *src, float *M, int height, int width, float scaleFactor, int minDistance)
{
    float nx,ny,nz, nzpminD, jFactor;
    int heightCenter = height / 2;
    int widthCenter = width / 2;
    //int j = blockIdx.x;   //Represents which row we are in
    int index = blockIdx.x*width;
    jFactor = (blockIdx.x - heightCenter)*scaleFactor;
    for(int i= 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        nz = src[index];
        nzpminD = nz + minDistance;
        nx = (i - widthCenter )*(nzpminD)*scaleFactor;      
        ny = (jFactor)*(nzpminD);   
        //Solve for only Y matrix (height vlaues)           
         dst[index++] = nx*M[4] + ny*M[5] + nz*M[6];
        //dst[index++] = 1 + 2 + 3;
    }
}

//Function fwd declarations
double getMillis();
double getMicros();
void runCudaTestZeroCopy(int iter, int cols, int rows);
void runCudaTestDeviceCopy(int iter, int cols, int rows);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    //ZERO COPY FLAG (allows runCudaTestZeroCopy to run without fail)
    cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);

    //Runs kernel using explicit data copy to 'device' and back from 'device'
    runCudaTestDeviceCopy(20, 640,480);
    //Uses 'unified memory' cuda abstraction so device can directly work from host data
    runCudaTestZeroCopy(20,640, 480);

    std::cout << "Stopping test" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void runCudaTestZeroCopy(int iter, int cols, int rows)
{
    cout << "CUDA Test::ZEROCOPY" << endl;
        int src_rows = rows;
        int src_cols = cols;
        int m_rows = 4;
        int m_cols = 4;
        int dst_rows = src_rows;
        int dst_cols = src_cols;
        //Create and allocate memory for host mats pointers
        float *psrcMat;
        float *pmMat;
        float *pdstMat;
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&psrcMat, src_rows*src_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&pmMat, m_rows*m_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&pdstMat, dst_rows*dst_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        //Create mats using host pointers
        Mat src_mat = Mat(cvSize(src_cols, src_rows), CV_32FC1, psrcMat);
        Mat m_mat   = Mat(cvSize(m_cols, m_rows), CV_32FC1, pmMat);
        Mat dst_mat = Mat(cvSize(dst_cols, dst_rows), CV_32FC1, pdstMat);

        //configure src and m mats
        for(int i = 0; i < src_rows*src_cols; i++)
        {
            psrcMat[i] = (float)i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m_rows*m_cols; i++)
        {
            pmMat[i] = 0.1234;
        }
        //Create pointers to dev mats
        float *d_psrcMat;
        float *d_pmMat;
        float *d_pdstMat;
        //Map device to host pointers
        cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&d_psrcMat, (void *)psrcMat, 0);
        //cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&d_pmMat, (void *)pmMat, 0);
        cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&d_pdstMat, (void *)pdstMat, 0);
        //Copy matrix M to device
        cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_pmMat, sizeof(float)*4*4 ); //4x4 matrix
        cudaMemcpy( d_pmMat, pmMat, sizeof(float)*m_rows*m_cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        //Additional Variables for kernels
        float scaleFactor = 0.0021;
        int minDistance = -10;

        //Run kernel! //cudaSimpleMult( float *dst, float *src, float *M, int width, int height)
        int blocks = src_rows;
        const int numTests = iter;
        double perfStart = getMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
        {           
            //cudaSimpleMult<<<blocks,1>>>(d_pdstMat, d_psrcMat, d_pmMat, src_cols, src_rows);
            cudaCalcXYZ<<<blocks,1>>>(d_pdstMat, d_psrcMat, d_pmMat, src_rows, src_cols, scaleFactor, minDistance);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        }
        double perfStop = getMillis();
        double perfDelta = perfStop - perfStart;
        cout << "Ran " << numTests << " iterations totaling " << perfDelta << "ms" << endl;
        cout << " Average time per iteration: " << (perfDelta/(float)numTests) << "ms" << endl;

        //Copy result back to host
        //cudaMemcpy(pdstMat, d_pdstMat, sizeof(float)*src_rows*src_cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        //cout << "Printing results" << endl;
        //for(int i = 0; i < 16*16; i++)
        //{
        //  cout << "src[" << i << "]= " << psrcMat[i] << " dst[" << i << "]= " << pdstMat[i] << endl;
        //}

        cudaFree(d_psrcMat);
        cudaFree(d_pmMat);
        cudaFree(d_pdstMat);
        cudaFreeHost(psrcMat);
        cudaFreeHost(pmMat);
        cudaFreeHost(pdstMat);
}

void runCudaTestDeviceCopy(int iter, int cols, int rows)
{
        cout << "CUDA Test::DEVICE COPY" << endl;
        int src_rows = rows;
        int src_cols = cols;
        int m_rows = 4;
        int m_cols = 4;
        int dst_rows = src_rows;
        int dst_cols = src_cols;
        //Create and allocate memory for host mats pointers
        float *psrcMat;
        float *pmMat;
        float *pdstMat;
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&psrcMat, src_rows*src_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&pmMat, m_rows*m_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        cudaHostAlloc((void **)&pdstMat, dst_rows*dst_cols*sizeof(float), cudaHostAllocMapped);
        //Create pointers to dev mats
        float *d_psrcMat;
        float *d_pmMat;
        float *d_pdstMat;
        cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_psrcMat, sizeof(float)*src_rows*src_cols ); 
        cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_pdstMat, sizeof(float)*src_rows*src_cols );
        cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_pmMat, sizeof(float)*4*4 ); //4x4 matrix
        //Create mats using host pointers
        Mat src_mat = Mat(cvSize(src_cols, src_rows), CV_32FC1, psrcMat);
        Mat m_mat   = Mat(cvSize(m_cols, m_rows), CV_32FC1, pmMat);
        Mat dst_mat = Mat(cvSize(dst_cols, dst_rows), CV_32FC1, pdstMat);

        //configure src and m mats
        for(int i = 0; i < src_rows*src_cols; i++)
        {
            psrcMat[i] = (float)i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m_rows*m_cols; i++)
        {
            pmMat[i] = 0.1234;
        }

        //Additional Variables for kernels
        float scaleFactor = 0.0021;
        int minDistance = -10;

        //Run kernel! //cudaSimpleMult( float *dst, float *src, float *M, int width, int height)
        int blocks = src_rows;

        double perfStart = getMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
        {           
            //Copty from host to device
            cudaMemcpy( d_psrcMat, psrcMat, sizeof(float)*src_rows*src_cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            cudaMemcpy( d_pmMat, pmMat, sizeof(float)*m_rows*m_cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            //Run Kernel
            //cudaSimpleMult<<<blocks,1>>>(d_pdstMat, d_psrcMat, d_pmMat, src_cols, src_rows);
            cudaCalcXYZ<<<blocks,1>>>(d_pdstMat, d_psrcMat, d_pmMat, src_rows, src_cols, scaleFactor, minDistance);
            //Copy from device to host
            cudaMemcpy( pdstMat, d_pdstMat, sizeof(float)*src_rows*src_cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        }
        double perfStop = getMillis();
        double perfDelta = perfStop - perfStart;
        cout << "Ran " << iter << " iterations totaling " << perfDelta << "ms" << endl;
        cout << " Average time per iteration: " << (perfDelta/(float)iter) << "ms" << endl;

        cudaFree(d_psrcMat);
        cudaFree(d_pmMat);
        cudaFree(d_pdstMat);
        cudaFreeHost(psrcMat);
        cudaFreeHost(pmMat);
        cudaFreeHost(pdstMat);
}

//Timing functions for performance measurements
double getMicros()
{
    timespec ts;
    //double t_ns, t_s;
    long t_ns;
    double t_s;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    t_s = (double)ts.tv_sec;
    t_ns = ts.tv_nsec;
    //return( (t_s *1000.0 * 1000.0) + (double)(t_ns / 1000.0) );
    return ((double)t_ns / 1000.0);
}

double getMillis()
{
    timespec ts;
    double t_ns, t_s;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    t_s = (double)ts.tv_sec;
    t_ns = (double)ts.tv_nsec;
    return( (t_s * 1000.0) + (t_ns / 1000000.0) );
}
```

I have already seen the post [Cuda zero-copy performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871449/cuda-zero-copy-performance), but I feel this was not related for the following reason: The GPU and CPUs have a physically unified memory architecture.

Thanks

Comment: [SO] isn't a discussion forum and this question isn't a very good fit for this place. If you have a concrete standalone question, with a short, complete code example which illustrates your problem, please edit it into your question. Putting a google drive link to code is counter productive. If the link breaks, the question is useless. Questions and answers exist as a permanent record to help both you, and future visitors with the same question or problem. I voted to close this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will remove the request for a 'discussion' and more explicitly make the bottom-line request, as my question is specifically  "How to use zero-copy efficiently on a physically unified memory architecture?" based upon my 2 provided methods.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ZeroCopy, the read to memory goes through some path where it queries the memory unit to fetch data from system memory. This operation has some latency.

When using direct access to memory, the memory unit gathers data from global memory, and has a different access pattern and latency.

Actually seeing this difference would require some form of profiling.

Nonetheless, your call to global function makes use of a single thread

```
cudaCalcXYZ<<< blocks,1 >>> (...
```

In this case, the GPU has little way to hide latency when memory is gathered from the system memory (or global memory). I would recommend you use more threads (some multiple of 64, at least 128 total), and run the profiler on it to get the cost of memory access. Your algorithm seems separable, and modifing the code from

```
for(int i= 0; i < width; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = threadIdx.x ; i < width ; i += blockDim.x)
```

will probably increase performance overall.
Image size is 640 in width which will turn into 5 iterations of 128 threads.

```
cudaCalcXYZ<<< blocks,128 >>> (...
```

I believe it would result in some performance increase.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, in adding more threads so there are 1 thread per pixel (480 blocks, 640 threads) this improved zero-copy slightly. However, in my zero-copy routine I made the 4x4 matrix a copy-to-device method, while the larger in and out matrices remained zero-copy. Now performance is huge (went from 8ms execution to 1ms execution). Should I upload the new code which represents this performance increase? I am still confused why zero-copy on the small matrix caused such a difference in access latency.

Comment: I also noticed that memory allocated with cudaHostAlloc has significant latency penalties when trying to access from the CPU thread to operate on. Is this common?

Answer (score 1):

ZeroCopy feature allow us to running data on device without manually copy it to Device Memory like cudaMemcpy function. Zero copy memory only pass host address to device that read/wrote on kernel device. So, the more thread block you declaration to kernel device, the more data that read/wrote on kernel device, the more host address that passed to device. Finally, you got better performance gain than if you only declaration a few thread block to device kernel.